# Pod with toleration is scheduled to node without taint

Tags: kubernetes

I have pod with this settings:

```
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 60s
                 role_va
```

The pod is scheduled into this node:

```
Labels:             balancer=true
                    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    cpu_avx2=true
                    cpu_avx512f=true
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=p20b-sr3-r5-k8s-node4
                    master=true
                    worker=true
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
Taints:             <none>
```

Please, help me understand why.
If I'm not mistaken the pod with toleration "role_va" must be scheduled **only** to node that has this taint.
In my case the node doesn't have this taint but the pod is scheduled into this node whatever. Why?

Answer (score 6):

As Malgorzata said, Taints and Tolerations are only useful for the nodes to accept a certain kind of pods. E.g. a node with "blue" taint can only accept pods with "blue" toleration. However, it does not mean that the pod with "blue" toleration would end up only in the node with "blue" taint. The Kube-Scheduler may pick up any other node that does not have a taint (and hence no preference of a pod type).

Below are two possible ways to achieve your requirements.

1. Apply the node with a taint and pod with that toleration. And also declare node affinity for the pod, which is a preference of a pod to get schedule on a particular node. These two configurations together would make sure that your pod would get scheduled on the specific node. And the node will only have the pods with a specific toleration.
2. If you have three nodes, apply "blue" taint on one of them and "red" taint on the rest of the nodes. That will force the pod with "blue" toleration only one choice to go on the node with "blue" taint. Because the other nodes have "red" taint and the pod does not have "red" toleration.

Answer (score 3):

Answer for your question is included in **Taints and Tolerations** definition in Kubernetes documentation: [`Taints and Tolerations`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/)

> The way Kubernetes processes multiple taints and tolerations is like a filter: start with all of a node’s taints, then ignore the ones for which the pod has a matching toleration; the remaining un-ignored taints have the indicated effects on the pod

That means if node **doesn't** have taints it will accept every pods, no matter what tolerations will be defined in them.